# How to calculate resultant gravitational acceleration in separate dimensions?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, physics

For example, if I want to know the resultant force in p, I don't need to find the magnitude and the angle of f1,f2 and f3, also no need to use any sin() and cos(), what I need to do is to add the force in x and y dimension separately in order to find resultant force f:

```
f.x=f1.x+f2.x+f3.x
f.y=f1.y+f2.y+f3.y
```

[image]

But now, I want to find the resultant gravitational acceleration in point p:

[image]

I know the mass and position of each ball, is there any method similar to  above finding resultant force that calculating resultant gravity g in separate dimension gx and gy, only using some simple operations to m1,x1,x2,m2...?

```
g.x=(some operations on m1,x1,y1,m2...)
g.y=(some operations on m1,x1,y1,m2...)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical physics

Comment: I disagree,mathematical physics only answer me about the formula of gravity, but not answer me the algorithm or technique to find g with x and y in separate dimensions

Comment: Did my formula answer to your need ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

The total force is, literally, the total of the forces.  You calculate the gravity due to each object and add them all together exactly as before.
Gravity for one of them is:

```
F = (G * mass1 * mass2) / (distance * distance)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation

Edit: It occurs to me I missed part of the question being asked.  Once you have the force, as above, you multiply it by the direction vector towards the planet center.  Google normalizing vectors, but basically:

```
Direction.X = (Planet.X - SpaceShip.X) / distanceToPlanet
and Y and Z
Force = GMm/rr * Direction
```

Comment: I also note that this means `Force.X = (Planet.X - SpaceShip.X) * GMm / rrr`.  That's non intuitive to me, but kind of neat ...

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to calculate a gravitational field in classical mechanics.

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field) gives the general formula but you have to do some calculations to get one only based on cartesian coordinates and masses.

We assume our model is in 2D. After some boring calculations, the resultant gravitational acceleration at the point P can be written :

[image]

[image]

with

- mi the mass of ball i
- (xi,yi) the position of ball i
- (xp,yp) the position of point P
- G the gravitational constant (6.674 e10−11 N.m2/kg2)

Those formulas use simple operations and can be easily implemented in languages such as c++, python or java.

NB : you have to respect G unit, i.e. coordinates in meter and mass in kilogram.